# Laravel : Get records from a table with 'where clause' from a field in another table

Tags: laravel

i have two tables . first is 'projects' with field id,name,number and second table is 'happenings' with fields id,project_id . these tables have one-to-many relationship . How can i get records from 'happenings' where their 'number' field in 'projects' is for example 5 .

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code sample so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

**SQL query :**

```
SELECT *, round(AVG(h.progress),0) as Progress FROM happenings h
JOIN projects p on p.id = h.project_id 
WHERE p.number = 5
```

**Eloquent :**

```
$data = DB::table('happenings as h')
->join('projects as p','p.id', '=', 'h.project_id')
->select('*', DB::raw('round(AVG(h.progress),0) as Progress'))    
->where('p.number','=',5)
->get();
```

Comment: many thanks . i have another field in 'happenings' named  'progress' . i want calculate average of  'progress' under above condition . indeed instead of get() , should be 'avg('progress') . but unfortunately not respond .

Comment: @saman I edit my answer. if it helped you, marked there as an answer.